# Is there a way to create a hotkey to print a specific string in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

I wanted to bind a string-paste to a specific hotkey, I use `console.log` a lot and really would help to have it binded on a hotkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Live template in

`Preferences | Editor | Live templates`

that would expand into a code snippet once you type the selected abbreviation and hit Tab.

For example, I write "cl" and when I press tab it transforms into `console.log(|)`

Comment: That's it, thanks...maybe I should explore jetBrains manuals a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

Add live template/snippet. All about snippets you can find [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm)

Comment: Thanks that works, that's a great reference and It will be helpful.